# RewriteRule with R=301 Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my .htaccess I have a rewrite rule that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)-([a-z_-]+)-(page)-([0-9]+)/?$ nation_notes.html?country=$1&title=$2&page=$3&pagenum=$4  [L,NC]
```

This allows my site to take a link like this:

`https://www.example.com/country/6-Argentina-page-1`

And display data from this:

`https://www.example.com/nation_notes.html?country=6&title=Argentina&page=1&pagenum=1`

However, Google started de-indexing my pages because they are "Page with redirect."  I would like the RewriteRule to specify that each of these is a R=301 (301 redirect).  However, when I add:

`[L,R=301,NC]`

Then the redirect breaks, and starts to add the root directory of my site to the URL, like this:

`https://www.example.com/home2/username/public_html/nation_notes.html?country=6&title=Argentina&page=1page&pagenum=1`

"home2/username/public_html/" is added to the URL, in the middle.  Obviously this breaks the code.

How can I fix this RewriteRule and add a 301 Redirect and still have everything functioning?

I have tried the following:

RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)-([a-z_-]+)-(page)-([0-9]+)/?$ nation_notes.html?country=$1&title=$2&page=$3&pagenum=$4  [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)-([a-z_-]+)-(page)-([0-9]+)/?$ nation_notes.html?country=$1&title=$2&page=$3&pagenum=$4  [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)-([a-z_-]+)-(page)-([0-9]+)/?$ nation_notes.html?country=$1&title=$2&page=$3&pagenum=$4  [R=301,L,NC]

... and other combinations of L, R-301 and NC.

This might be useful: my full .htaccess file looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)-([a-z_-]+)-(page)-([0-9]+)/?$ nation_notes.html?country=$1&title=$2&page=$3&pagenum=$4  [L,NC] # rewrite for country with page number

RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)-([a-z_-]+)/?$ nation_notes.html?country=$1&title=$2-page-1 [L,NC] # rewrite for country without page number

RewriteRule ^banknote/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9_-]+)-p([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_-]+)-from-([0-9]+)/?$ view_banknote.html?id=$1&countryname=$2&pick=$3&denomination=$4&currency=$5&year=$6 [L,NC] # rwrite for banknote

RewriteRule ^collector/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ view_collector.html?user=$1&name=$2 [L,NC] # rwrite for collector

RewriteRule ^collection/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ view_collection.html?collection=$1 [L,NC] # rwrite for collection

RewriteRule ^collection-country/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_.-]+)/?$ view_collection.html?collection=$1&country=$3 [L,NC] # rwrite for country within collection

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ view_article.html?news=$1&title=$2 [L,NC] # rwrite for news articles

RewriteRule ^nationinfo/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ nation_info.html?country=$1&title=$2 [L,NC] # rwrite for country info

RewriteRule ^search-results-([0-9]+)/?$ banknote_search.html?resultpage=$1 [L,NC] # rwrite for banknote search results

RewriteRule ^search-results-([a-zA-z0-9]+)/?$ banknote_search.html [L,NC] # rwrite for banknote search results with non numeric page num

RewriteRule ^viewnote.html/?$ money_gallery.html [L,NC] 

RewriteRule ^nation.html/?$ money_gallery.html [L,NC] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://realbanknotes.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://realbanknotes.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.realbanknotes.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.realbanknotes.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://realbanknotes.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://realbanknotes.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.realbanknotes.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.realbanknotes.com$      [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following htaccess rules file. Also I have made few fixes in your rules file. Also make sure your .htaccess file is present inside `public_html` folder; clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /home2/username/public_html/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# rewrite for country with page number
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)-([a-z_-]+)-(page)-([0-9]+)/?$ nation_notes.html?country=$1&title=$2&page=$3&pagenum=$4  [L,NC]

# rewrite for country without page number
RewriteRule ^country/([0-9]+)-([a-z_-]+)/?$ nation_notes.html?country=$1&title=$2-page-1 [L,NC]

# rwrite for banknote
RewriteRule ^banknote/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9_-]+)-p([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_-]+)-from-([0-9]+)/?$ view_banknote.html?id=$1&countryname=$2&pick=$3&denomination=$4&currency=$5&year=$6 [L,NC]

# rwrite for collector
RewriteRule ^collector/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ view_collector.html?user=$1&name=$2 [L,NC]

# rwrite for collection
RewriteRule ^collection/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/?$ view_collection.html?collection=$1 [L,NC]

# rwrite for country within collection
RewriteRule ^collection-country/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z_.-]+)/?$ view_collection.html?collection=$1&country=$3 [L,NC]

# rwrite for news articles
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ view_article.html?news=$1&title=$2 [L,NC]

# rwrite for country info
RewriteRule ^nationinfo/([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ nation_info.html?country=$1&title=$2 [L,NC] 

# rwrite for banknote search results
RewriteRule ^search-results-([0-9]+)/?$ banknote_search.html?resultpage=$1 [L,NC] 

# rwrite for banknote search results with non numeric page num
RewriteRule ^search-results-([a-zA-z0-9]+)/?$ banknote_search.html [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(viewnote|nation).html/?$ money_gallery.html [L,NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://realbanknotes.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://realbanknotes.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.realbanknotes.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.realbanknotes.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://realbanknotes.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://realbanknotes.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.realbanknotes.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.realbanknotes.com$      [NC]
```

Comment: RavinderSingh13, thank you for your reply.  When I implement the code you have provided, I get error 404 all over my site -- none of the rewrite rules work, and I can't figure out why because no errors are generated in the error log.

Comment: @xProteuSx, please mention path of your htaccess and your actual files path.

Comment: .htaccess is in the /public_html/ directory.  The /public_html/ directory is in root, like this: /home2/username/public_html/.  I have changed the "username" to the actual username, so it should have worked.